# Adding multiple UI elements dynamically

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I have an layout as show above. The problem I am facing now is that for the view enclosed within the red rectangle, I want to duplicate it and append it below based on a count. How about should I do this? Is it possible for me to use a nib to add it dynamically? Or I have to add the UI elements using code? If so, how should I retrieve the value from the textfield that is dynamically added?

Comment: If you also await scrolling, I would go uitableview way. You can place table view and scale it within your parent view.

Comment: Dynamic UI elements will be easier. Make the red outlined as a parent view and add 2 child views

Comment: Both answers are great but I prefer to use UItableview because is more easy and can get better code. The other way is using Dynamic UI element and create frame with anchor and add child or ussing constrains programatically with Dynamic UI. My best experience is with UITableView, you need 2 rows? Only 1 line in tableview numberOfRowsInSection.

Comment: Alright thanks for your suggestions.